# Supervise changes in object property values

Tags: delphi

I want to supervise instances of a class. Whenever a property of that object got changed, I'd like to be able to check on that, without implementing that feature myself. Especially if the class has numerous attributes.

I've got a class like this:

```
TMyClass = class
private 
  FTest1: Integer;
  ...
  FTestN: Integer;
public
  property Test1: Integer read FTest1 write FTest1;
  ...
  property TestN: Integer read FTest1 write FTest1;
end.
```

And when use this class:

```
c := TMyClass.Create;
```

It would be awesome to have something like:

```
c.changed // -> false
c.Test1 := 1;
c.changed // -> true
```

Is there a standard way to do that?

Comment: What you're asking for isn't entirely clear. Are you looking for a way to sense when an object's properties have been modified without resorting to triggering events for each property's getter?

Comment: Note that your example is not clear since `changed` is a temporal property: what should it return after the second `c.changed`? Should it be reset to false assuming that only one client checks for changes or should it remain true? Also, are you willing to change `TMyClass` or do you want to sense changes from the outside (which is not possible)?

Comment: Please, precise your Delphi version (add the appropriate specific tag)!

Answer (score 4):

The typical pattern used is a setter method in a property, as Brian puts in option #1. I felt like writing you some sample code, so you can see what people do.

Note that NameChanged is a virtual method because I might want to declare a base class TPersonInfo, and then create a subclass later for TJanitorInfo, and TJanitorInfo might have a more complex implementation for `NameChanged`.  So one level of planning for handling property value changes is that subclasses can override methods.  But for something which is not a subclass, you've suggested in your question setting a boolean flag to true. That would then require "repeating checking for that flag" (known as polling) somewhere. That might in the end be more work than it's worth.  Maybe what you need is what is shown below as an "Event", also known as a "callback" or a "pointer to a method".  In delphi these properties start with the word `On`.  `OnNameChanged` would be such an event.

```
 type
   TPersonInfo = class
        private
          FName:String;
          FOnChangedProperty:TNotifyEvent;
        protected 
           procedure SetName(aName:String);
           procedure NameChanged; virtual;
        published
           property Name:String read fName write SetName;

           property OnChangedProperty:TNotifyEvent read FOnChangedProperty write FOnChangedProperty;

   end;

 ...
 implementation 

   procedure TPersonInfo.SetName(aName:String);
   begin 
      if aName<>FName then begin
        aName := FName;
        NameChanged;
      end;
   end;

   procedure NameChanged; virtual;
   begin
      // option A: set a boolean flag. Exercise for reader: When does this turn off?
      FNameChanged := true;
      // option B: refresh visual control because a property changed:
      Refresh;
      // option C: something else (math or logic) might need to be notified
      if Assigned(FOnChangedProperty) then
              FOnChangedProperty(Self);
   end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some research on this subject and played with the [`TAspectWeaver` demo](http://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/source/browse/?r=268#svn/trunk/Samples/AOP) from the  [DSharp project](http://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/) to achieve this goal:

```
unit Aspects.ChangeDetection;

interface

uses
  DSharp.Aspects,
  Rtti,
  SysUtils,
  StrUtils;

type
  TChangeDetectionAspect = class(TAspect)
  private
    class var IsChanged : Boolean;
  public
    class procedure DoAfter(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
      const Args: TArray<TValue>; var Result: TValue); override;
    class procedure DoBefore(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
      const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean;
      out Result: TValue); override;
    class procedure DoException(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
      const Args: TArray<TValue>; out RaiseException: Boolean;
      Exception: Exception; out Result: TValue); override;
  end;

  ChangeDetectionAttribute = class(AspectAttribute)
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  [ChangeDetection]
  IChangeable = interface
  ['{59992EB4-62EB-4A9A-8216-1B14393B003B}']
    function GetChanged: Boolean;
    procedure SetChanged(const Value: Boolean);
    property Changed : boolean read GetChanged write SetChanged;
  end;

  TChangeable = class(TInterfacedObject, IChangeable)
  private
    FChanged : Boolean;
    function GetChanged: Boolean;
    procedure SetChanged(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    property Changed : boolean read GetChanged write SetChanged;
  end;


implementation

{ TChangeDetectionAspect }

class procedure TChangeDetectionAspect.DoAfter(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; var Result: TValue);

var ic : IChangeable;

begin
 if Supports(Instance, IChangeable, ic) then
  ic.Changed := IsChanged;
end;

class procedure TChangeDetectionAspect.DoBefore(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean; out Result: TValue);

var ctx  : TRttiContext;
    typ  : TRttiType;
    meth : TRttiMethod;
    Res  : TValue;

begin
 IsChanged := False;
 if StartsText('set', Method.Name) then
  begin
   ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
   typ := ctx.GetType(Instance.ClassType);
   // call Getxxx counterpart
   meth := typ.GetMethod('G'+ Copy(Method.Name, 2, Maxint));
   if Assigned(meth) then
    try
     Res := meth.Invoke(Instance, []);
     IsChanged := Res.AsVariant <> Args[0].AsVariant;
    except
    end;
  end;
end;

class procedure TChangeDetectionAspect.DoException(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; out RaiseException: Boolean; Exception: Exception;
  out Result: TValue);
begin

end;

{ ChangeDetectionAttribute }

constructor ChangeDetectionAttribute.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(TChangeDetectionAspect);
end;

{ TChangeable }

function TChangeable.GetChanged: Boolean;
begin
 Result := FChanged;
end;

procedure TChangeable.SetChanged(const Value: Boolean);
begin
 FChanged := Value;
end;

end.
```

Usage:

```
unit u_frm_main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Aspects.ChangeDetection, DSharp.Aspects.Weaver;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  IMyObject = interface(IChangeable)
    function GetName: String;
    procedure SetName(const Value: String);
    property Name : String read GetName write SetName;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TChangeable, IMyObject)
  private
    FName : String;
  public
    function GetName: String;
    procedure SetName(const Value: String); virtual;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyObject }

function TMyObject.GetName: String;
begin
 Result := FName;
end;

procedure TMyObject.SetName(const Value: String);
begin
 FName := Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var MyObject : IMyObject;
begin
 MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
 MyObject.Changed := False;
 AspectWeaver.AddAspect(TMyObject, TChangeDetectionAspect, '^Set');
 MyObject.Name := 'yee';
 if MyObject.Changed then
  ShowMessage('yep changed');
 MyObject.Name := 'yee';
 if MyObject.Changed then
  ShowMessage('oops, not changed should not display');
 MyObject.Name := 'yeea';
 if MyObject.Changed then
  ShowMessage('yep changed');
end;

end.
```

Please note that you should have at least Delphi2010 for this to work.

I prefer Warren's answer though (less magic), I just wanted to show it is possible (with virtual function proxies)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I know of doing this and neither are neat. It would be great if we had an OnProperyChanged event but we don't, so you have to do something yourself. Options are:

1. Set a CHANGED Boolean inside a property setter procedure for each of your properties.
2. Use RTTI to keep a shadow copy of all your property data and compare with the copy on a timer to set a CHANGED flag if different.

I would be very interested to know a better way.

Comment: virtual proxy function is another way (see my answer)